# Regular expression - identifying double quotes only inside of curly brackets

Tags: r, regex, string, csv

I am totally stumped by a problem with regular expressions. I have a comma delimited file where some fields are an array of values enclosed with two double quotes. These double quotes are messing up my table read function and I need a regular expression to identify these double quotes so that I can remove them.

FYI -- the language I am using is R, but I don't think that is relevant.

For example, the file looks like:

```
val1,,,val4,val5,"this is another value","{""Value 1"",Value2,""Value 3"",Value4,Value5}"
```

I want to remove the two double quotes enclosing values inside of the curly brackets, but leave everything else as is.

I would like a regular expression to identify these two double quotes, so that I can use a replace function to remove them. I would like the output to be:

```
val1,,,val4,val5,"this is another value","{Value 1,Value2,Value 3,Value4,Value5}"
```

So same as above but no double quotes inside the curly brackets.

Any help is much appreciated. Please feel free to offer a different approach if you think I should go about this another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this will solve your problem... If you're only trying to <s>get rid of</s> match those double quotes

```
\"\"
```

[RegEx Example](https://www.regex101.com/r/ZouoTv/1)

Comment: In R: `gsub('""', '', x)`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to separate and reassemble the string:

```r
x <- 'val1,,,val4,val5,"this is another value","{""Value 1"",Value2,""Value 3"",Value4,Value5}"'

x2 <- paste0(gsub('(.*\\{).*', '\\1', x),    # capture up to {
             gsub('"', '', gsub('.*\\{(.*)\\}.*', '\\1', x)),    # remove quotes of inside {}
             gsub('.*(\\}.*)', '\\1', x))   # capture after }

cat(x2)
#> val1,,,val4,val5,"this is another value","{Value 1,Value2,Value 3,Value4,Value5}"
```